# Region problem when starting cold .net application

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm showing a splash screen in my .net application and in my OnLoad override I am setting the Region property to rounded rectangle, so that the splash screen appears to have curved corners.  This works brilliantly, except for when the program is started cold; then the area outside the region (in the four corners) temporarily appears black instead of transparent. Anyone have any ideas on why the cold start may affect the UI layout?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: What's a cold start of a program?

Comment: Examples of cold startups are when your app starts for the first time after a reboot or if you start an application, close it, and then launch it again after a long period of time. When an application starts up, if the pages required are not cached by the OS memory manager, disk access is needed to bring those pages into memory.
In the warm startup scenario (eg you have already run a managed application once) it is likely that most of the pages for the main CLR components are already loaded in memory from where the OS can reuse them, saving expensive disk access time.

Comment: I am pretty sure that has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't have much else to go on at the moment.  When I debug the program the corners appear black whilst the various referenced assemblies are being loaded by the CLR (I can see this from the output window).  Once all of the assemblies are loaded the corners become transparent.

Comment: Is the Message pump running when you show the splash screen?

Comment: No, the screen is put up just before Application.Run is called.  Do you think that might be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you set the Region inside the constructor of the Form but after the InitializeComponent? At that point the size of your form will be defined and so you can correctly decide on the Region required. This would define the region before the window handle is created.

If that turns out to be too early then try overriding the OnHandleCreated and do it after calling the base class.

Comment: Thanks Phil, That's helped a lot. BTW, we use your Krypton controls on almost all of our products and we think they're fantastic!

Comment: Nice to hear about another satisfied customer!